# String manipulation to identity patterns in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to find patterns in a list of strings.

| String | Expected String (desired result) |
| --- | --- |
| #string-string-string-string-9999-9999 | #string-9999 |
| #string-string-9999-9999-9999 | #string-9999 |
| #string-9999 | #string-9999 |
| #string-9999-string | #string-9999-string |
| #string-string-string-string-9999-9999-string | #string-9999-string |

Here ("expected string" column), I am trying to reduce the consecutive alphabet and numeric part of the string to identify patterns. Can someone help me with this?

I used the bpa library, but did not achieve the desired result.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific in what pattern you're looking for to get a good response. Is each string/number actually sectioned by dashes? Is it really in the structure you mentioned or do you sometimes have stringA-stringB-999-stringA or something? If you do sometimes have that and no dashes, how do you determine where A stops and B begins? Each of these will change the answer.

Comment: I think you are not "trying to find patterns" in the sense that many readers of the question would assume (that is, using regular expressions) but rather, trying to simplify the strings using some de-duplication rules.

Answer (score 3):

use the regular expression pattern "\b(\w+)(-\1)+\b" to match consecutive duplicate words separated by a hyphen (-) character:

```r
x <- c(
  "#string-string-string-string-9999-9999",
  "#string-string-9999-9999-9999",
  "#string-9999",
  "#string-9999-string",
  "#string-string-string-string-9999-9999-string"
)

gsub("\\b(\\w+)(-\\1)+\\b", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```